# KL ( Kullback-Leibler) distance with histogram smoothing in Python

Tags: python, histogram, gaussian, smoothing

I have two lists ( of different lengths) of numbers.
Using Python, I want to calculate histograms with say 10 bins.
Then I want to smooth these two histograms with Standard kernel (gaussian kernel with mean = 0 ,sigma=1)
Then I want to calculate the KL distance between these 2 smoothed histograms.
I found some code about histogram calculation but no sure about how to apply standard kernel for smoothening and then how to calculate the KL distance.
Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For calculating histograms you can use [numpy.histogram()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) and for gaussian smoothing [scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html). Kullback-Leibler divergence code can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/yyf6efXs).

Method to calculate do the required calculation would look something like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

def kl(p, q):
    p = np.asarray(p, dtype=np.float)
    q = np.asarray(q, dtype=np.float)

    return np.sum(np.where(p != 0, p * np.log(p / q), 0))

def smoothed_hist_kl_distance(a, b, nbins=10, sigma=1):
    ahist, bhist = (np.histogram(a, bins=nbins)[0],
                    np.histogram(b, bins=nbins)[0])

    asmooth, bsmooth = (gaussian_filter(ahist, sigma),
                        gaussian_filter(bhist, sigma))

    return kl(asmooth, bsmooth)
```